# rndc querylog - Can you specify log file other than messages?

Tags: logging, bind

When logging `BIND` requests using `rndc querylog`, the logging defaults to `/var/log/messages`. Is it possible to change this logging destination and specify my own log file?

Answer (score 0):

In the man pages for named.conf, there is a section on logging.

Just make sure that if you are using a chroot for your DNS service, that your log destination is interpreted properly.

Specifically, the syntax chart is as follows:

> ```
>       logging {
>             channel string {
>                  file log_file;
>                  syslog optional_facility;
>                  null;
>                  stderr;
>                  severity log_severity;
>                  print-time boolean;
>                  print-severity boolean;
>                  print-category boolean;
>             };
>             category string { string; ... };
>       };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes! You can define a query log channel and direct that output to a specific log file destination of your choosing if you do not want this in the syslog messages file.

```
 channel queries_log {
      file "/var/named/log/queries" versions 600 size 20m;
      print-time yes;
      print-category yes;
      print-severity yes;
      severity info;
 category queries { queries_log; };
```

Remember that you can enable and disable query logging using rndc as needed for debugging issues. This will help save you some CPU cycles and disk I/O when operations are normal. Adjust the sample I posted so that you do not end up with 600 20MB files with logged queries sitting on your file system.

Just as a matter of practice, try to have a dedicated partition and file system for your logs so that filling it up will not negatively impact other system operation.
i.e. putting /var/log on it's own partition/slice. Worst case if that fills up you may loose some log data however system functions can continue.